# No Challenge session id or Challenge node id in discoverAndAddAccounts() in API explorer

Tags: aggregation, intuit-partner-platform, customer-account-data-api

I've tried to add a CIBC account using the API explorer interface. I've got back a 401 response with response body specifying a challenge. However, in the response header, there is only "content-length", no challenge session id or challenge node id as expected. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, there is an UI bug in the CAD ApiExplorer. It is not returning the challange nodeId and sessionId. It should be fixed soon.

Ideally this 'DiscoverAndAddAccounts' API call returns a response like following.

[image]

In the mean time, you can try this call using java/.net devkit

Ref code(java) - https://github.com/IntuitDeveloperRelations/IPP_Sample_Code/blob/master/CustomerAccountData/Java/AggCatSampleApplication/src/main/java/com/intuit/aggcat/AggCatApiController.java

[Method - discoverAndAddAccounts(HttpServletRequest request, Model model)]

[ For CC_Bank use 'tfa_text2' as userid and 'anyvalue' as pwd]

Devkit and Sample App Link - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/devkits

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a valid bug in ApiExplorer and will be fixed as part of the aug 23rd patch. Sorry about the inconvenience. Like mentioned ,in the interim, you can use one of the sdk's.